# Using a custom keystore with Jetty's WebSocketClientFactory

Tags: java, security, ssl, jetty, cometd

I have a Java project that is connecting to a CometD server over a secure WebSocket transport which uses a self-signed certificate. I'm configuring the `WebSocketClientFactory` in the following way:

```java
wssFactory.getSslContextFactory().setKeyStorePath("/path/to/my/custom.jks");
wssFactory.getSslContextFactory().setKeyStorePassword("mypass");
```

And then create my `BayeuxClient` like so:

```java
BayeuxClient client = new BayeuxClient(
        "wss://myserver.com/cometd",
        WebSocketTransport.create(clientOptions, wssFactory));
```

Indeed, when this first gets loaded, things seem to be configured properly:

```
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,786 : starting org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory@75cfa3d2
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,786 : starting qtp2005556553{8<=0<=0/254,-1}
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,788 : STARTED qtp2005556553{8<=7<=8/254,0}
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,788 : starting org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory$WebSocketClientSelector@50c8c3b8
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,795 : STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory$WebSocketClientSelector@50c8c3b8
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,795 : Starting Thread[qtp2005556553-33 Selector0,5,main] on org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1@346fe350
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,797 : starting SslContextFactory@4240eca3(/Users/apetresc/Downloads/infrastructure.jks,null)
[INFO ] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,981 : Enabled Protocols [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1] of [SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1]
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,981 : Enabled Ciphers   [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] of [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA, TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5]
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,981 : STARTED SslContextFactory@4240eca3(/Users/apetresc/Downloads/infrastructure.jks,/Users/apetresc/Downloads/infrastructure.jks)
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 12:58:05,981 : STARTED org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory@75cfa3d2
```

And, indeed, **actually using the `BayeuxClient` works**. However, it would work even if I didn't specify a keystore at all -- it just treats it as an unsigned certificate. And, indeed, that seems to be what is happening, judging by the error logs I keep getting every few seconds:

```
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : State update: CONNECTED -> CONNECTED
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : Connecting, transport org.cometd.websocket.client.WebSocketTransport@53ddbcb1
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=START buffer= g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=-1} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : Sending messages [{id=50, connectionType=websocket, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=2u16ol79fcq7hqe1wu52pr0ws4aw}]
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : Registering WebSocketExchange {id=50, connectionType=websocket, channel=/meta/connect, clientId=2u16ol79fcq7hqe1wu52pr0ws4aw}
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=OPCODE buffer= g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=-1} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : Sending messages [{"id":"50","connectionType":"websocket","channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"2u16ol79fcq7hqe1wu52pr0ws4aw"}]
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,348 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=OPCODE buffer= g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=116} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,349 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=OPCODE buffer=null g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=116} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,349 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] wrap OK NOT_HANDSHAKING consumed=116 produced=137
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,349 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=OPCODE buffer=null g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=137/0
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,349 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=OPCODE buffer=null g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=0} NOT_HANDSHAKING filled=0/0 flushed=0/0
[DEBUG] 2012-08-07 13:20:37,349 : [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL] handle SslConnection@79c190a2 SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING i/o/u=0/0/0 ishut=false oshut=false {WebSocketClientConnection p=WebSocketParserRFC6455@5266db4e state=OPCODE buffer=null g=WebSocketGeneratorRFC6455@5ec80825 closed=false buffer=-1} progress=false
```

To me this implies that the *CometD* handshake is completing, but the *SSL* handshake is not. I can't figure out why this is the case, though; an analogous approach is working for my HTTPS calls. It's only the WSS that's giving me a headache.

May also be worth mentioning that I can reproduce this in various different environments, including an Android app and from within a Jetty servlet container.

Has anyone successfully used WSS with a self-signed certificate? Care to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As a short aside, does anyone find the error code `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` as hilariously uninformative as I do? :)

Comment: `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` almost certainly refers to the null cipher suite, which doesn't provide any authentication or encryption (and which should never be enabled...).

Comment: @Bruno: Can you expand on that? Judging from the logging output, my cipher suite is *anything* but NULL (it appears to have dozens of entries).

Answer (score 5):

In the second code block you are not getting any "error". That is the normal output for an unconfigured `SslContextFactory`, which provides the null cipher suite and a always approving certificate verifier.
See also here for further `SslContextFactory` [configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/SSL_Connectors).

From the logs you have it working in both cases.

For a more generic answer to your question, when you use self-signed certificates, you may want to configure the `SslContextFactory` with a trust store, so that the certificate verification can use it to verify the self signed certificate.

Other than that, seems to me that you have setup your code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about `WebSocketClientFactory`, but as far as I understand, it's for client-side configuration, where you're essentially trying to connect to a server configured with a self-signed certificate, a copy of which is stored in your `custom.jks` file on the client.

What you need for accepting a self-signed certificate on the client side isn't to set its keystore (which is used for client-certificate authentication from this side), but to set its truststore.

Try replacing `setKeyStore*` with `setTrustStore*`.